# Why well-known ports?

Tags: sockets, ports

Why is there this distinction between the registrated ports in well-knows and normal registred ports? 
Why if I decide to bind a socket on 23 I need the root privileges while on the port 1025 I do not need? What reason brought to this decision?
 And why, let's suppose I make a software that use a socket it is better to register the port on which it bind itself?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about history, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the time of multiuser unix systems in university campuses, where normal users never had root access, unix systems were using ports below 1024 to indicate that the process that created the port/connection was 'trusted' by the local admin. This was used to f.e. indicate what the local user name in system A was so that a connection would use that user in system B.

Comment: SOrry I don't understand, if normal users never had root access how could they run a program that binds an a port that requires root privileges?<br> I don't understand "This was used to f.e. indicate what the local user name in system A was so that a connection would use that user in system B" who needed to know the local user name?

Comment: Say you have a service like [rsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell) - a simple remote shell that can be configured to authenticate users without a password. It runs port 514. Let's say we have systems A and B that are trusting each other. User foo connects from A to B using rsh, which is setuid root so that it can bind to privileged ports. After rsh connects to system B, the rsh daemon in B looks at the source port of the connectin in system A, and sees that it is below 1024, hence started by a system-approved process, hence system B can trust the user id passed over the connection.

Comment: User-generated programs that aren't approved by the system (they are not setuid root) cannot connect using source ports below 1024, hence they cannot pass spoofed user IDs. Also, if a service isn't running (consider system C that does not have an rsh daemon), a user-created process does not have the right to use that port to listen, hence it cannot grab connections that went to system C mistakenly.